# Edit Comment via Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

I've gone through the documentation. I haven't found anything that suggests you can edit a comment (or status update for that matter) after it's posted.

Does anyone know if you can?

I suppose you could delete and repost a comment, however it becomes less than real time.

J

Comment: What if you commented on something, I liked your comment and then you totally changed your comment? (let it be political opinion or anything else).

Comment: I understand the issue at heart. But imagine the possibilities for an application if you could funnel through a 3rd party service (or edit after the fact) a comment between entry and display. You could turn a :) into an image. You could turn the text "Call Me" into a funny image and display that instead (like half of my friends do - communicating with pictures and expressions instead of words) Or turning conversations into conversations with facts. Referencing video, image, and other resources automatically. 

That's what I wanna do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can edit a comment/status once it has been posted. I mean, if Facebook users can't edit their previously-posted status updates, why would Facebook allow apps to do so?

Comment: Thanks. 

Well they sort of let you edit, if you delete within a certain time period... I suspect that time period is the time before the notification is sent to other users.

It's unfortunate. I'm sure it will be added at some point... maybe. Unless there's a legitimate concern about the veracity of the conversation.

Comment: I'm guessing that time period is very short? My guess is that you'd have to do what you initially suggested and delete/repost.

Comment: It is mondo short. Like 20 - 30 seconds. 

Unfortunate.

Comment: Users can edit their posts: http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2012/06/22/facebook-is-now-rolling-out-the-ability-to-edit-your-comments-on-status-updates/

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late, but as of May 2014, you can edit a comment in Facebook SDK. 
You follow the exact same procedure as in posting a new comment, with the difference that *you also provide the* `comment-id` *of the comment you want to be updated*.

Here's the source from the Facebook documentation:
[Graph API Comment Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/comment/)